# Is this a basis for the set S?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the set: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Would the basis be found by doing:
a$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ +
$b\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

So those two 2x2 matrices would form the basis? Is this the proof that they form a basis? 
How do I prove they're linearly independent? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

a $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ +
$b\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ $=0$, the zero matrix

If you show that $a=b=0$, then the matrices are linearly independent.

Also, the fact that they span the set is obvious.

Comment: I don't get how to show a=b=0. That's the part I was confused on, because if I multiply them back out, I just get my set.

Comment: Why don't you multiply the scalars to the corresponding matrices and add the two up.

Comment: When I do that, I just get 
$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: i mean, if a=b=0 for this, then it would be the zero matrix....?

Comment: Yes!! You got it.

Comment: Sweet, thanks!! It didn't seem like it would be that easy. Haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes those two matrices form a basis for the vector space $$V = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{bmatrix} |  \ a, b \in K \right\}$$ as evidently every member of $V$ can be written as such a linear combination.

The show linear independence, just explain why

$$a \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} + 
b\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 0  \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{ if and only if } \ \ \ \ \ a = b = 0$$